# Strip information from xpath?

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, html-parsing

I use the following line of code to fetch CVE id's from a webpage:

```
  project.cve_information = "".join(xpath_parse(tree, '//div[@id="references"]/a/text()')).split()
```

But, the problem is:

```
            <div id='references'>
            <b>References:</b>
            <a href='https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2011-3256' target='_blank'>CVE-2011-3256&nbsp;<i class='icon-external-link'></i></a>
            <a href='https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2011-1402.html' target='_blank'>RHSA-2011-1402&nbsp;<i class='icon-external-link'></i></a><br />
        </div>
```

References: CVE-xxxx-xxxx  RHSA-xxxx-xxxx

How do I avoid RHSA and such entries from being parsed? I just want the CVE-xxxx-xxxx values. I use it to submit to a form like this:

```
          "form[CVEID]" : ",".join(self.cve_information) if self.cve_information else "GENERIC-MAP-NOMATCH",
```

This form performs validation only on CVE values and errors out since my code tends to include RHSA values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *contains*:

```
h = """ <div id='references'>
            <b>References:</b>
            <a href='https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2011-3256' target='_blank'>CVE-2011-3256&nbsp;<i class='icon-external-link'></i></a>
            <a href='https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2011-1402.html' target='_blank'>RHSA-2011-1402&nbsp;<i class='icon-external-link'></i></a><br />
        </div>"""

from lxml import html

xml = html.fromstring(h)

urls = xml.xpath('//div[@id="references"]/a[contains(@href, "CVE")]/@href')
```

Or if you wanted to ignore the hrefs with RHSA you could use *not contains*:

```
urls = xml.xpath('//div[@id="references"]/a[not(contains(@href, "RHSA"))]/@href')
```

Both would give you:

```
 ['https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2011-3256']
```

Comment: Umm, I think I did not explain my problem correctly. I am using xpath expressions to parse the "references" field. I then use the "CVE-xxxx-xxxx" id's elsewhere so that it would be https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-xxxx-xxxx. 

With the current solution, I get - WARNING: Failed to find info on CVE CVE-2011-3256 - an extra "CVE" infront of CVE-2011-3256

Comment: Do you want `CVE-2011-3256`? If they are always at the end just rsplit on `/` and extract, if they can be anywhere then you need either a regex or split and use str.strartswith to find the sub string you want

Comment: Change the xpath from `/@href` to `/text()`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Just edited it a bit more to get what I wanted.